# Downloading a Zip File with Java gets it corrupted

Tags: java, download, inputstream

I just tried to download a file from a Website, i checked the URL and everything seems to be fine there, but when i try to do it like described it prints out that my update size is `-1 Bytes`, don't know why this is happening.

If anyone has a solution, i would be glad to here it.

My Code:

```
    private void downloadFile(String link) throws MalformedURLException, IOException
{
    URL url = new URL(link);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    long max = conn.getContentLength();
    outText.setText(outText.getText()+"\n"+"Downloding file...\nUpdate Size(compressed): "+max+" Bytes");
    System.out.println("Update Size --> " + max + " Bytes");
    BufferedOutputStream fOut = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("update.zip")));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[32 * 1024];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    int in = 0;
    while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        in += bytesRead;
        fOut.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    fOut.flush();
    fOut.close();
    is.close();
    outText.setText(outText.getText()+"\nDownload Complete!");
}
```

Big Thanks already :)

Answer (score 0):

[The javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength%28%29) is your friend:

> Returns:
>       the content length of the resource that this connection's URL references, **-1 if the content length is not known, or if the content length is greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE**.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Well I guess i didn't nail the question there ... sorry, my fault. Actually my question was how to fix the corrupted ZiP-File... if you could answer me this question too, that would be great! :)

Comment: @njoye There's nothing about that in your question. Please fix it.

Comment: @njoye your code looks fine to me. Are you sure the URL is the URL of a zip file? What happens if you open the downloaded file as a text file, for example?

Comment: Try using `curl` on the same URL; it may be that the server expects some prerequisites that the browser is providing (e.g. an authenticated session, or a particular header such as an Accept header).

Comment: @JB Nizet you were right, it downloads the source code, not the file